# How to clip circle in android

Tags: java, android, custom-view, clip

I need to clip custom circle button. I did it by the viewgroup, cause i need image in center. So i need to make it so that when pressed near the button it does not work. Here is code of this view:

```
public class CircleCustom extends ViewGroup {

private static final int Circle_RADIUS_DEF = 120;
private Paint mPaintSquare;

private int mSquareColor;
private int mSquareSize;

private int width;
private int height;

private Path path;

private ImageView mButIconImage;

public CircleCustom(Context context) {
    super(context);

    init(context);
}

public CircleCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    init(context);
}

public CircleCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    init(context);
}


private void init(Context context) {

    mButIconImage = new ImageView(context);
    mButIconImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_fitness_center_black_24dp);
    addView(mButIconImage);

    mPaintSquare = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    mSquareColor = Color.GREEN;
    mSquareSize = Circle_RADIUS_DEF * 2;

    mPaintSquare.setColor(mSquareColor);

    path = new Path();
}


@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    widthMeasureSpec = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);

    measureChild(mButIconImage, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    setMeasuredDimension(mSquareSize, mSquareSize);
}


@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    final int width = r - l;

    mButIconImage.layout(
            Circle_RADIUS_DEF - mButIconImage.getMeasuredWidth() / 2,
            Circle_RADIUS_DEF - mButIconImage.getMeasuredHeight() / 2,
            Circle_RADIUS_DEF + mButIconImage.getMeasuredWidth() - mButIconImage.getMeasuredWidth() / 2,
            Circle_RADIUS_DEF + mButIconImage.getMeasuredHeight() - mButIconImage.getMeasuredHeight() / 2
    );
}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawCircle(Circle_RADIUS_DEF, Circle_RADIUS_DEF, Circle_RADIUS_DEF, mPaintSquare);

    canvas.translate(0,0);

    path.addCircle(Circle_RADIUS_DEF, Circle_RADIUS_DEF, Circle_RADIUS_DEF, Path.Direction.CCW);
    canvas.clipPath(path);

    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}
```

Im trying to clip it right here :

```
path.addCircle(Circle_RADIUS_DEF, Circle_RADIUS_DEF, Circle_RADIUS_DEF, Path.Direction.CCW);
    canvas.clipPath(path);
```

I didnt find any info about clipping custom circle.
Im already tried to do this with Rect and Arc. Both dont work.

Answer (score 0):

I belive this is your problem simplified - you have a button that is a circle, but button clicks work as if it had a surface of a square? Correct me if I'm wrong.

If that is true, you could ditch using Paint class and upload the button as a vector or an image into a drawable. Then, create an ImageView out of it and set onClickListener on that.

Comment: "button clicks work as if it had a surface of a square". What do u mean when saying "button" ? Just view with OnClickListener, or Button like a class ?